# Swift Generic UIView subclass with protocol issue

Tags: ios, generics, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I have extended **UIView** to conform **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** protocol

The below code compiles

```
let label = UILabel()
let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: label.self, action: Selector("tapGestureHandler:"))
recognizer.delegate = label.self
label.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
```

Now I am trying to create a Generic Subclass to create different UIView subclass's

```
class MyView<T:UIView> {
    init() {
        (T.self as T.Type).init(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    func addGestureToView() {
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: T.self, action: Selector("tapGestureHandler:"))
        // The below two lines produces syntax error    
        recognizer.delegate = T.self // does not conform to protocol 'UIGestureRecognizerDelegate'
        T.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer) // UITapGestureRecognizer cannot convertible to UIView
    }
}
```

The strange thing to me is, **T.addGestureRecognizer** expects UIView rather than **UIGestureRecognizer**

**Update**:

I want the return type of MyView to be subclass of UIView,

```
let view = MyView<UIView>()
```

// I want to use it this way

```
view.tintColor = UIColor.redColor() // I can't
```

// But, I have to use this way

```
view.subview.tintColor = UIColor.redColor()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`T` is the type of your subview. You must create an instance of it to call `addGestureRecognizer` and to set it as a delegate of a gesture recognizer.

```
class MyView<T:UIView where T: UIGestureRecognizerDelegate> {
    var subview: T

    init() {
        subview = T(frame: CGRectZero)
    }

    func addGestureToView() {
        let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: subview, action: Selector("tapGestureHandler:"))

        recognizer.delegate = subview
        subview.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
    }
}
```

Note that you're assuming that the class passed to create a MyView instance has a method named `tapGestureHandler:`. You should probably add this method to a protocol and make `T` conform to it too.

Comment: Please check my update comments, 
In case, if this is the only way that I can do what I needed, then I will accept this as answer

Comment: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28262520/can-i-use-swift-generic-in-this-case) this is what I actually wanted to solve